# Ionic: refresher not working on iOS home screen app, working in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA with Ionic and I have a ion-refresher in my app:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="refresh()">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="lines"></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
...
</ion-content>
```

On my iPhone, in the browser the refresher is working fine (I can pull down on the screen and it will reload the page). When I add the app to my home screen however, it stops working.

Any ideas? Here are the packages I use:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~9.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.51",
    "@types/gapi.client.drive": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "decimal.js-light": "^2.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.13.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, weird enough, it works on certain pages but a specific one. not sure why. did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me what did the trick is that I was missing

```
viewport-fit=cover
```

from the "viewport" meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but it seems I already have the `viewport-fit=cover` inside the viewport meta. The strange thing is also that the refresher works from the browser but not anymore when it's added as an app on the home screen of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the attribute force-overscroll in the ion content

```
<ion-content force-overscroll="true"> 
.
.
.
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting mode="ios" to bot ion-refresher and ion-refresher-content. the only way i got it fixed.